# Mysql connection pooling with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

I've searched around for a while but I am still not sure of the advantages and disadvantages of a connection pool vs a single permanent connection (using the [mysql package](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)).

Currently am using the single connection option but due to scalability issues I am thinking of switching to a pool.

I am not really sure what common pitfalls I have to look for, but here are some I think.

a) `SELECT/UPDATE`(s) that need to be sequential must be used inside a transaction.

b) release each connection in the narrowest scope possible.

c) Be careful of selecting data about to be changed and updated so use `FOR UPDATE` to lock them.

Generally I would like to know about the pitfalls. Also, suppose I use a transaction into each and every query, would that make it perform the same as having a single connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple. Are you going to do more than 1 MySQL query in parallel, you need it.

Whether you do that depends on your application. Is it a webserver serving more than 1 user?

Comment: Yes am going to do a lot more than 1. In the low thousands. I am just not sure if weird issues will occur, such as if two users decide to update the same row, (since two requests will go to the DB from two connections) which will be processed? How can I avoid such race conditions?

Comment: Most database queries can run in parallel just fine, even on the same table. If you're doing 2 queries that conflict with each other, one of the two (or one of the two transactions) will fail.